# How to convert the ASP.NET pages as PDF and download the same(values are not static)

Tags: c#, html

I have developed a webpage which allow users to enter the values just like a registration form.While saving the data I need to give an option for downloading the page as PDF format.

I tried the following:

1. I tried using itextsharp dll. The problem is I don't get all the content in the PDF files. Example images and styles are not converted properly.
2. I tried some third party tools like( SautinSoft's PdfVision, ConvertApi, pdfcrowd)assemblies. All the dll are getting the URL as a parameter and converting into PDF. In that way the server side HTML code is converted into PDF.the values that I have entered are not in the PDF.

Sample code I got from net for (sautinsoft).

```
 SautinSoft.PdfVision v = new SautinSoft.PdfVision();
        v.PageStyle.PageSize.Letter();
        byte[] pdf = v.ConvertHtmlFileToPDFStream(@"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page");
        if (pdf != null)
        {
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/PDF";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition:", "attachment; filename=Result.pdf");
            Response.BinaryWrite(pdf);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
```

**for (itextsharp)**

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
StreamWriter twr = new StreamWriter(mem);
HtmlTextWriter myWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(twr);
base.Render(myWriter);
myWriter.Flush();
myWriter.Dispose();
StreamReader strmRdr = new StreamReader(mem);
strmRdr.BaseStream.Position = 0;
string pageContent = strmRdr.ReadToEnd();
strmRdr.Dispose();
mem.Dispose();
writer.Write(pageContent);
CreatePDFDocument(pageContent);


}

public void CreatePDFDocument(string strHtml)
{

string strFileName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("test.pdf");
// step 1: creation of a document-object
Document document = new Document();
// step 2:
// we create a writer that listens to the document
PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(strFileName, FileMode.Create));
StringReader se = new StringReader(strHtml);
HTMLWorker obj = new HTMLWorker(document);
document.Open();
obj.Parse(se);
document.Close();
ShowPdf(strFileName);


}

public void ShowPdf(string strFileName)
{
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + strFileName);
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.WriteFile(strFileName);
Response.Flush();
Response.Clear();
}
```

Let me know if you have a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this library for what you are trying to achieve

http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

here is tutorial on how to use it

https://gist.github.com/2341776

Answer (score 0):

At a previous job we had paid licenses for the Persits Software AspPDF.NET (and "classic" AspPDF) which worked pretty well. Had no trouble with CSS not applying or images being left out of the PDF - though too be fair we never uses anything that could be considered "advanced" CSS. I think you can try a free demo that will watermark the PDFs you make until you buy & apply a registration key.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this solution:

```
        string inpFile = @"https://google.com";
        string outFile = new FileInfo("Result.pdf").FullName;
        // Local chromium will be downloaded into this directory.
        // This takes time only at the first startup.
        string chromiumDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(@"..\..\..\..\..\..\Local Chromium\").FullName;

        PdfVision v = new PdfVision();
        
        HtmlToPdfOptions options = new HtmlToPdfOptions()
        {
            ChromiumBaseDirectory = chromiumDirectory,
            PageSetup = new PageSetup()
            {
                PaperType = PaperType.Letter,
                Orientation = Orientation.Portrait,
                PageMargins = new PageMargins()
                {
                    Left = LengthUnitConverter.ToPoint(5, LengthUnit.Millimeter),
                    Top = LengthUnitConverter.ToPoint(5, LengthUnit.Millimeter),
                    Right = LengthUnitConverter.ToPoint(5, LengthUnit.Millimeter),
                    Bottom = LengthUnitConverter.ToPoint(5, LengthUnit.Millimeter)
                }
            },
            PrintBackground = true,
            Scale = 1
        };

        try
        {
            v.ConvertHtmlToPdf(inpFile, outFile, options);
            // Open the result for demonstration purposes.
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(outFile) { UseShellExecute = true });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

But you need to know, that if you are running it in the first time. It will take 2-3 min because need the time to download Chromium engine